# Why isn't Docker Compose honoring my POSTGRES_USER environment variable?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I know lots of questions sound like this, and they all have the same answer: delete your volumes to force it to reinitialize.

The problem is, I'm being careful to delete my volumes, but it's consistently spinning up the container incorrectly every time.

### My *docker-compose.yml*

```yaml
version: "3.1"
services:
  db:
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=changeme
      - POSTGRES_USER=myuser
    image: postgres
```

My process:

```sh
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER   VOLUME NAME
$ docker-compose up -v # or docker-compose up --force-recreate
```

yet it always creates the "postgres" user instead of `myuser`. The output when it starts up shows that it "will be owned by user 'postgres'" and I can only docker exec as postgres, not my user.

The instructions seem very straightforward. Am I missing something, or is this a bug?

What happens when you use the compose file above?

Comment: Because that is the way it is supposed to be. See here [postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) and read the section `POSTGRES_USER`.

Comment: Do you mean that it creates a database user called 'postgres,' or a Linux user called 'postgres'? To my knowledge, the `POSTGRES_USER` variable only controls the first thing, and there isn't a way to control the second thing in the official Docker image.

Comment: It seems like you probably shouldn't need `docker exec` at all here.  "Get a shell inside a database" doesn't seem like an ordinary use case, and if you do it shouldn't matter what Linux user you are so long as the filesystem permissions match up.  I wouldn't worry about this use case, and just connect to the database with `psql` or a language-native client library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can only `docker exec` as *postgres*, not *myuser*

The environment variable `POSTGRES_USER` controls the database user, not the linux user. Take a look at the chapter *Arbitrary --user Notes* in the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) to learn how to change the linux user.